# How do i calculate the least commom multiple between two numbers on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to calculate the least common multiple between two numbers in JavaScript for a homework, can someone help me?

I was trying to use this code:

```js
var n1, n2, i = 0,
  LMC = 1,
  max, min; //Initializing Variables

n1 = Number(prompt("Type the first LMC´s Number"));
n2 = Number(prompt("Type the second LMC´s Number"));
max = Math.max(n1, n2);
min = Math.min(n1, n2);

//Using loop to check all possible multiples
while (max > 1 && min > 1 && c <= min) {
  if (i != 1) { //If the i was different of 0 
    if (max % c == 0 && min % c == 0) { //And the division with max and min was 0 

      max /= c; //Then divide the max and min
      min /= c;
      LMC *= c; //And multiply the LMC according to the multiple
    }

  }
  i++; //Increase i 
  alert("N1: " + n1 + "\n" + "N2: " + n2 + "\n" + "LMC: " + LMC); //Show result
}
```

Comment: Where is `c` defined?

Comment: Unrelated quick tip: you can easily get the max and min using `[min, max] = [n1, n2].sort()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```js
// program to find the LCM of two integers

// take input
const num1 = prompt('Enter a first positive integer: ');
const num2 = prompt('Enter a second positive integer: ');

// higher number among number1 and number2 is stored in min
let min = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;

// while loop
while (true) {
  if (min % num1 == 0 && min % num2 == 0) {
    console.log(`The LCM of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${min}`);
    break;
  }
  min++;
}
```

- The while loop is used with an if statement. In each iteration,
- The variable min is divided by both the num1 and num2.
- If both numbers' remainders are equal to 0, then it is the LCM and
  the break statement terminates the program.
- If both numbers' remainders are not equal to 0, the value of min is
  increased by 1 and the loop continues

I took this script from [Here](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/lcm)